# Matlab: Can't find a circle with imfindcircles

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I want to understand how `imfindcircles` works, so I created a simple image with black background and a single white circle. The image is 640x480 and the circle has a diameter of 122 pixels:

[image]

I tried to use `imfindcircles` to detect the circle, I have tried various modes of the image, as `uint8` RGB, `uint8` grayscale, `double` grayscale and the reversed image, in all those forms, and with various values for `minR` and `maxR`. I got no result in all cases:

```
minR = 40;
maxR = 80;
Irgb = imread('example_circle.png');
Irgbr = 255 - Irgb;
I = rgb2gray(Irgb);
Ir = 255 - I;
Id = double(I)/255;
Ird = 1 - Id;

[c1,r1] = imfindcircles(I,[minR maxR]);
[c2,r2] = imfindcircles(Ir,[minR maxR]);
[c3,r3] = imfindcircles(Id,[minR maxR]);
[c4,r4] = imfindcircles(Ird,[minR maxR]);
[c5,r5] = imfindcircles(Irgb,[minR maxR]);
[c6,r6] = imfindcircles(Irgbr,[minR maxR]);

disp([length(r1) length(r2) length(r3) length(r4) length(r5) length(r6)]);
```

The output is:

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0
```

How am I supposed to use the function to find the circle?

Comment: Binary inputs often give the best result, but based on the documentation it should also work for gray and RGB images. Using binary image: `[c1,r1] = imfindcircles(I>128,[minR maxR]);`

Comment: You may find more information in [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+imfindcircles)

Comment: @m7913d, it worked for a binary image, but not for a reverse binary image (black circle with white background), but I can't work with binary images, I need to use the function in another program which has more complex images.

Comment: Concerning reverse binary, you can use `'ObjectPolarity','dark'` option. Concerning non-binary, I don't know. Hopefully, someone else does.

Comment: `imfindcircles` works best on binary images.  For grayscale images, circles are found such that the interior of the region has some difference away from the background.  It's not recommended, but it can be done.

Comment: I've also linked to an answer I wrote in the past on how to use `imfindcircles` properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`imfindcircles`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.htm) function has a `'Sensitivity'` parameter:

> As you increase the sensitivity factor, imfindcircles detects more circular objects, including weak and partially obscured circles. Higher sensitivity values also increase the risk of false detection.

By setting the Sensitivity to a higher value, you get more potential circles. You could tune this parameter to always give you one circle, e.g. `0.95` seems to work fine in this specific case. This is probably not very robust though.

```
[c1, r1] = imfindcircles(Irgb,[40,80], 'Sensitivity', 0.95)
```

If you know that there will always be *exactly* one circle, you can set the Sensitivity to `1`, which returns *all* potential circles. Then, use the `metric` output, which gives you the calculated strength of a detected circle. As you know there will be exactly one circle, you can just take the strongest one, which is always the first row.

```
[c, r] = imfindcircles(Irgb,[40,80], 'Sensitivity', 1);
c1 = c(1,:);
r1 = r(1,:);
```

Comment: I was wondering why you deleted your post.  Thank you for undeleting. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you. As you can see from the edit history I basically created a new answer. I made a mistake when downloading the sample image: it appears that the preview image has a smaller resolution than the real image, so the radius was correct, unlike I wrote in the first version of the answer.

Comment: I understand!  But yes, this is the correct answer.  The expected radii parameters are not being used correctly, and you've also alluded to the `Sensitivity` parameter.

Comment: I still have a question about the answer that you edited. In there you wrote that you got a result when you reduced the radius search to 20-40, was it made on the full sized picture or the reduced one?